# Prevent Search Results Being Truncated - Drupal 7

Tags: search

Is there a way to prevent Drupal from truncating the search results?

That is, I do not want the search results shortened with a "..." added to the end of the result. I would like the full text.

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. Copy the `/modules/search/search-result.tpl.php` file into your `theme` directory. Then modify it like this:

```
  <?php /* this is just so it will be easier to access the body of the node */ ?>
  <?php $node = $variables['result']['node']; ?>
  <li class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <h3 class="title"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
    <a href="<?php print $url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
  </h3>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
  <div class="search-snippet-info">
  <?php if ($snippet): ?>
  <p class="search-snippet"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php /* this part is modified, you could display different data then the body */ ?>
    <?php print $node->body[$node->language][0]['safe_value']; ?>
  </p>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php if ($info): ?>
    <p class="search-info"><?php print $info; ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</li>
```

**Note** Like I said in the comment, it's easy to display content from some other field, not just the body. To see what data you have to play with do:

```
 <?php echo '<pre>';
       print_r($variables);
       echo '</pre>';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the snippet by preprocessing the search results. Replace test in the module name below with the name of your module and you'll be good to go. I don't really know my way around D7 yet, but I think the 'und' part of the node array implies that you're only using one language on your site.

```
function test_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  $variables['snippet'] = $variables['result']['node']->body['und'][0]['safe_value'];
}
```

Comment: Both are still valid @KristerAndersson sometimes people prefer a theme solution rather than a module solution.

Comment: That's true, I actually tried the `theme_preprocess_search_result` at first but I like templates=)